# Py_DECREF segmentation fault

Tags: python, c++, embedded-language

I am having trouble embedding Python in C++. I am using Mingw w64 gcc and 64 bit Python 2.7.11.

```
#include <Python.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    Py_Initialize();

    PyObject* pName = PyString_FromString("test");

    Py_DECREF(pName);

    Py_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```

Calls to compiler:

```
g++ "-IC:\\Python27\\include" -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -std=c++11 -o "src\\main.o" "..\\src\\main.cpp" 
g++ "-LC:\\Python27\\libs" -std=c++11 -o pytest.exe "src\\main.o" -lpython27
```

The problem is that it segfaults in Py_DECREF. I have tried expanding the macros, and have traced segfault to the following statement:

```
((*(((PyObject*) ((PyObject *) (pName)))->ob_type)->tp_dealloc)((PyObject *) ((PyObject *) (pName))));
```

Turns out, tp_dealloc points to 0x1.

The same problem happens in the example code provided in Python docs:
https://docs.python.org/2/extending/embedding.html#pure-embedding

If I remove some of the calls to Py_DECREF(pName) and Py_DECREF(pArgs), code from the docs works as intended. Yet every example I've found on the web (including the one from the Python docs) does call Py_DECREF.

What could be the cause of this error? Could there be some inconsistency in my build environment?

Answer (score 0):

So, apparently, something is wrong with my environment. I tried compiling the same code on another PC and there was no segfault anymore.